# tvOS - pressesEnded doesn't work on start

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv

I'm trying to give the app same behavior as YouTuBe where when top `TabBar`  is visible and user presses Menu Button on remote, the app should exit.

So I override `pressesBegan` and `pressesEnded`

```
override func pressesBegan(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {

}
```

**Yeah nothing in it, otherwise the app exits no matter what is the condition in** `pressesEnded`

```
override func pressesEnded(presses: Set<UIPress>, withEvent event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    if let type = presses.first?.type where type == .Menu {
        if navigationController.viewControllers.count == 1 {
            if isTabBarOpen {
                super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
            } else {
                self.showTabBar()
                self.setNeedsFocusUpdate()
                self.updateFocusIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    } else {
        super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event)
    }
}
```

So my issue is on the app start (from terminated state, not background state), if I press Menu Button on remote, the `if isTabBarOpen{ super.pressesEnded(presses, withEvent: event) }` gets executed but the app never exit unless I move the focus.

**Edit**

I tried both initial focus on `TabBar` or `RootViewController`

Let me know if you need more info :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use gesture recognizer to catch Menu button press?

```
    // add the hook to detect menu button press
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "menuPressed:")
    tap.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
    window.rootViewController?.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap) // add it to your view controller

    func menuPressed(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer){
       print("menu press")   
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't use gesture because one of the subview's initial focus is on keyboard (the search page). I have to use a lower level function like `pressesBegan` and `pressesEnded`